# Erro no Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi-xe5

Alguém consegue entender o por que que isso vem ocorrendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na verdade, não é só isso aí não, tem muito mais, sempre que digito um caractere especial ";" ou outras coisas, ele não reconhece e fica dando esse erro.

Mas quando vai para compilar, ele compila normalmente.

Mas em algumas funções que desejo ver como funciona e não me mostra.

(**Só para constar, estou utilizando o Delphi xe5 para Android (FireMonkey)**)

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Tudo isto que tu falou eu ja tentei, gastei horas e horas apenas para tirar esse erro, é chato msm kkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, eventualmente acabei descobrindo que era um sistemazinho que eu utilizo chamado Castalia v2013.2, aonde morava este erro, claro, com a saida da versão 2013.4, foi resolvido este erro.

Aparentemente este erro foi causado devido a um bug que esta versão do castalia tem em relação ao desenvolvimento de apps, no caso do Delphi, o Firemonkey, ainda nao estava completo o desenvolvimento desta ferramenta para operar juntamente com o desenvolvimento mobile via delphi.

Obrigado.